# Python Discord How to send message?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to send message manually without waiting for user to send. Basically I want to be able to remind user when a http request is done server-side and message user,

```
from discord.ext import commands



client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get user with id and send him a message. Example:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.get_user(USER_ID).send("Text Message")
```